# How to make hexagone type of imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview

Hello thanks in advance, here i want to make imageview hexagon or pentagon i refer this tutorial but i am not able to modify points. So is that any change required for rotate hexagon 90 degree or any other way. I used following code for hexagon but this code gives me hexagon but i want same output with 90 degree rotation.

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) {
        Bitmap finalBitmap;
        if (bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius)
               finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius,
                            false);
        else
               finalBitmap = bitmap;
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap.getWidth(),finalBitmap.getHeight(),Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                     finalBitmap.getHeight());

        Point point1_draw = new Point(75, 0);
        Point point2_draw = new Point(0, 50);
        Point point3_draw = new Point(0, 100);
        Point point4_draw = new Point(75, 150);
        Point point5_draw = new Point(150, 100);
        Point point6_draw = new Point(150, 50);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(point1_draw.x, point1_draw.y);
        path.lineTo(point2_draw.x, point2_draw.y);
        path.lineTo(point3_draw.x, point3_draw.y);
        path.lineTo(point4_draw.x, point4_draw.y);
        path.lineTo(point5_draw.x, point5_draw.y);
        path.lineTo(point6_draw.x, point6_draw.y);

        path.close();
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rotate the canvas with 90 degrees before drawing, and restore it after drawing.

```
canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
canvas.rotate(90);//or -90
//Do drawing here
//canvas.drawPath(...)
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: thank you reply,but this code not working,not rotate canvas .

Comment: Here is a complete example using the same approach: http://android-er.blogspot.hk/2014/06/draw-rotated-path-by-rotating-canvas.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this library :- https://github.com/MostafaGazar/CustomShapeImageView

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Thank you for reply, Is that possible without any lib ?

Comment: Yes but its easy if you use a library. :)

Comment: thank you, me already used this lib is work perfect. but i have make pragmatically, not used any lib

Answer (score 0):

canvas.save();

canvas.rotate(90, 90, 90);

//draw canvas
 canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

canvas.restore();